# Download all attachments in a model RAILS

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, view, controller

I am using `rails4` with `paperclip` and `rails_admin` gems and I am trying to make a link which when clicked will download all the attachments from the submission table.

Here is my code

`rails_admin/main/index.html.haml`

```
- if @abstract_model.table_name == "submissions"
        = link_to "Download all", '/downloadAttachments'
```

`submission_controller.rb`

```
# Download zip file of all submission
  def download
    @submissions = Submission.all

    file = @submissions[0].file.url(:original, false) #folder to save the archive to

    Zip::ZipFile.open(file, create=nil) do |zipfile|
      @submissions.each do |filename|
       zipfile.add(filename.file_file_name, filename.file.url(:original, false))
      end
    end
  end
```

`routes.rb`

```
get '/downloadAttachments' => 'submissions#download'
```

When I click the link though, I get a message `Cannot find submission with id downloadAll`. From my experience with rails, that method should get called and create the downloadable zip for me. Question: what is wrong with this def and how can I get that zip downloaded?

[EDIT]

This code seems to work, but it's getting a:

```
File /files/submissions/files/45/original/file.pdf not found
```

But I can confirm that file definitely exists in my public folder

Comment: From my guess, the action is not going to submissions, but to the rails_admin default action for that page :index

Comment: Try this match "/admin/submission/downloadAll" => 'admin/submission#downloadAll', via: :get, as: "admin_submission_downloadAll" And add url  "/admin/submission/downloadAll"

Comment: can you paste the output of `rake routes | grep submissions` in the question? The error must belong to the order of routes defined in routes.rb

Comment: From the error, i believe it is going to some route `/admin/submissions/:id` with `id: 'downloadAll'` which must be mapped to some member action inside submissions controller

Comment: Please see my edit. With this code above seems to get sent to the right controller, but now I get a not found error

Comment: Please also paste the output of above command. That will help.

Comment: It is going to the route now @jagdeep, it was just about nopt having `admin` namespace in the route. Now, why is it not getting that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

`submission_controller.rb`

```
# Download zip file of all submission
  def download
    @submissions = Submission.all

    archiveFolder = Rails.root.join('tmp/archive.zip') #Location to save the zip

    # Delte .zip folder if it's already there
    FileUtils.rm_rf(archiveFolder)

    # Open the zipfile
    Zip::ZipFile.open(archiveFolder, Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) do |zipfile|
      @submissions.each do |filename|
        zipfile.add(filename.file_file_name, 'public/files/submissions/files/' + filename.id.to_s + '/original/' + filename.file_file_name)
      end
    end

    # Send the archive as an attachment
    send_file(archiveFolder, :type => 'application/zip', :filename => '2016 Submissions.zip', :disposition => 'attachment')
  end
```

`routes.rb`

```
get '/downloadAttachments' => 'submissions#download'
```

In the view then:

```
= link_to "Download All", '/downloadAttachments'
```

Answer (score -2):

I think your link_to code has a wrong format. The second parameter should be a path/route:

`= link_to "Download all", {:controller => "/submissions", :action => "download"}`

or

`= link_to "Download all", download_submissions_path`

Comment: This is not the issue. If I do that I will get a no route error

Comment: is your submission controller under /admin folder? if yes, maybe ```= link_to "Download all", /admin/submissions/download``` will work?

Comment: no, admin is just a namespace came from rails_admin, so my submission controller is under controllers